# Adding UPC Attribute to Product Page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I need to have an attribute "UPC:" displayed on my product pages when a UPC Number is entered in the backend. I need it to display just below the SKU#. I followed instructions from another post and by using their suggestion I was able to get the # to show in the right place, however the issue is the label UPC: is not showing just like the SKU: label does. Something is missing in the custom code. If anyone else has a better solution than I tried, I am willing to remove what I tried and start this from scratch.

Below is the codes and files I used.

You can display custom attributes by creating block after the sku block in catalog_product_view

Create catalog_product_view.xml in "app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_custom_attr" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_attr.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product_custom_attr" destination="product.info.stock.sku" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create custom_attr.phtml file in "app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\custom_attr.phtml"

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?><div class="product attribute">
<div class="value"><?php echo $_product->getData('upc_code') ?></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Marius, it seems you replied to my question with an edit. I am trying to figure out if there was a change in the code as to what I need to use. I looked at what appeared to be edited and see no change than what I already had. Can you post the correct codes I need for each file for this to work. I am still having issues with this or provide the best solution to get the UPC attribute to work on the product page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module in app/code

Create catelog_product_view.xml in app/code/Name/Module/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<page xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" layout=""1column""
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name=""product.info.stock.sku"">
            <block class=""Name\Module\Block\Product\View"" name=""magenest_per_pox""
                   template=""Name_Module::product/view/custom_attr.phtml""/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create filehandle and get data in Name\Module\Block\Product\View.php

Create custom_attr.phtml in app/code/Name/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/custom_attr.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \Name\Module\Block\Product\View $block */
?>
<?php if ($block->getAttribute()) : ?>
    <div>
        <span>
            Test: <?php echo $block->getAttribute(); ?>
        </span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```